# How to properly disable Linux deep C-States for a specific Core?

Tags: linux

On Linux OS CPUs run on different power-saving states called the C-states. They are ranging from C0 to Cn. C0 is the state with maximum performance, but consume more power. So to maximize performance one can disable transition to deeper states. There is two way to disable C state transitions.

The global way that affect all the CPUs by writing 0  to the **/dev/cpu_dma_latency** file.
Or the per CPU way by writing “n/a” to the **/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu<cpu_id>/power/pm_qos_resume_latency_us** file.
References:
https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/howto/applications/cpuidle
https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/pm/cpuidle.html

Then I have the following questions:

1. Except the number of core that are affected, are **pm_qos_resume_latency_us** and **cpu_dma_latency** files really acting the same? Why one is called "dma latency" while the other is called "resume latency"?
2. For the **cpu_dma_latency** file, opening the file causes a new PM QoS request to be created. The file descriptor coming from the "open" operation represents that request. If that descriptor is then used for writing, the number written to it will be associated with the PM QoS request created.
   Closing the the file descriptor causes the PM QoS request to be destroyed.

**Does the pm_qos_resume_latency_us file act the same? Does closing the file descriptor obtained causes the associated PM QoS request to be destroyed?**

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question, so it's off-topic on Stack Overflow. You may be able to ask this on one of the Linux sites, like Unix & Linux SE, Ask Ubuntu, Super User, or Server Fault. See also the [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) tag description.

Comment: I am updating the question

Comment: I think it is unlikely that this question can be edited to be on-topic on SO. Having code does not make a question a programming question. You'll likely get a better response if you migrate it to a site where system administration question are on-topic.

Comment: This is not a question **about** the C language, so it should not have the C tag.